# Create a Link with javascript to copy inside the clipboard

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a link using the selected text with the mouse and associate the URL of the website. After copy inside the the clipboard through javascript, so i can paste the link directly inside excel.

```
Mousetrap.bind('shift+d', function() {

    let oggi = new Date().toLocaleString("it-IT");

    function getSelectionText() {
        let testoSelezionato = ""
        if (window.getSelection) {
            testoSelezionato = window.getSelection().toString()
        }
        return testoSelezionato
    }

    let selezionatore = function(){
        let testo = getSelectionText()
        let pagina = window.location.href;

        let unione = testo +" "+ oggi + "\n" + pagina;
        if (testo.length > 0) {
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(unione);
        }
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", selezionatore);
    }
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', selezionatore, false);

});
```

This is what i've done using the Mousetrap library.
The problem is that currently i'm pasting in two separate row because i do not know how to associate the link to the selected text.

**Edit:**
my purpose is to copy the link in a similar way  Microsoft Edge does, if you try to copy the url inside Edge browser and paste it into excel it will create a link with the text displayed instead of the url. But i want to decide the text to display.

Comment: "*i do not know how to associate the link to the selected text.*" what is that supposed to mean? How to create a string that is reconized as link with text in excel?

Comment: Probably similar to creating a link in html, `<a href='link url here'>display text here</a>`

Comment: @derpirscher Yes, exactly. But i want to put the text/link into the clipboard, and after manually paste it into the excel sheet.

Comment: @James I'm making some tests with the clipboard API and also pasting the entire link string from the html but it paste me only the url and not the text with connected the url